# Cancel VWP return flight after entering USA

Tags: us-visa-waiver-program, norwegian-air-shuttle

I will travel to the USA under Visa Waiver Program. Thus I will leave the US inside 90 days but for a number of reasons not relevant to this question I do not yet know exactly when I'll depart. Since one needs an onward flight from the USA to be admitted under the VWP I'll have to book one anyway.

I thought of booking a Economy Flex ([Fare Rules](https://www.norwegian.com/us/booking/booking-information/fare-rules/international-long-haul-flex/)) flight with Norwegian and canceling it as soon as I have been admitted.

Are there any problems with this plan? Will Norwegian refund the whole price or are there some fees or taxes that will be deducted or are not refundable? Will I be able to travel inside the US by plane?

Comment: The link says `Cancelling Flex or PremiumFlex Fully refundable and can be cancelled online.` Typically that means exactly what it says, fully refundable. I have previously purchased such tickets although on Delta, not Norwegian.

Comment: Why not buy an Economy Flex with the return date set 90 days from your arrival, then change the flight when you know your departure date?

Comment: @Spaig87 It might be cheaper to buy a new ticket in a different fare class, even shortly before departure.

Comment: @MichaelHampton least it shows the CBP officer OP will be able to return home. I've been US for 90 days before and I got confused with my return and the flight was over the 90 days as I didn't realise entry classed as day 1. The CBP officer just told me to change my return home so I don't overstay.

Comment: @Spaig87 Exactly for the reason MichaelHampton mentioned. A flight for next Friday from LAX to CDG currently costs 410€ in LowFare and 750€ in Flex.

Comment: @ThEiLlEgAlaLiEn Thanks, that's great to hear.

Comment: @BritishSam the ticket requirement is actually statutory.  It's not just about showing an ability to leave.  But the ticket need not be booked for a specific date, and it need not be to the point of origin.  It only needs to be to a destination outside of North America and the Caribbean (or to the traveler's country of residence if it is in North America or the Caribbean).  Also the US used to count the date of entry as day zero; I'm not sure when they changed.